# JQuery Validation Plugin Inside A Fancybox Window

Tags: jquery, validation, fancybox

how to use jQuery validate script inside a fancybox plugin.I tried to use that but the form is automatically submitted.Any one help me to fix this issue

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  $("#frmManagement").each(function(){
        $(this).validate();
        }) ;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple questions. It alpears you are using multiple forma with the same html id, eg. id="frmManagement"... This is bad practice.   You should have a unique id per html element.  If that's not true, and you have one element of frmManagmeny, then I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  $("#frmManagement").validate();
  });
```

Otherwise, you could keep it as is (I assume) and return false inside your foreach as jQuery could be bubbling up the form submit event.